# See $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^{n-1}}$ as a Beta distribution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, probability-distributions, beta-function

Let $n>4, x>0$. I need help with this integral. Using Wolfram,I get that it is $\frac{2\Gamma(n-4)}{\Gamma(n-1)}$, as if it was a Beta distribution with parameters $(3,n-4)$, but I can’t see how to transform this expresion, I can only obtain that it is a Beta$(3,2-n)$.

Also, I do it in a more exhaustive way, using a change of variable and I got $\frac{n^2-6x+10}{(n-3)^2(n-4)}$. Can someone explain me how to get the result of Wolfram?

Comment: How did you get to $\beta(3, 2-n)$? Can you update that in the question?

Comment: @OctavioHernandez Welcome to Math SE. With your result of $\frac{n^2-6\color{red}{x}+10}{(n-3)^2(n-4)}$, should the $\color{red}{x}$ be $\color{red}{n}$ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result given by Wolfram Alpha is the right one.

Explanation: take a look at this very well done [site](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/05%3A_Special_Distributions/5.18%3A_The_Beta_Prime_Distribution) ; you will see there that you shouldn't refer to a Beta distribution but to a "Beta prime" distribution with pdf:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{B(a,b)}\frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^{a+b}}$$

here with $a=3$ and $b=n-4$.

Just express that

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)=1$$

in order to get

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^{a+b}}=B(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}=\frac{2\Gamma(n-4)}{\Gamma(n-1)}$$

which is indeed the result given by WA.

Comment: See as well Wikipedia [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn’t aware that this distribution actually exists. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Letting $y=\frac{1}{1+x}$ transforms the integral into a beta function as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_1^0\left(\frac{1}{y}-1\right)^2 \cdot y^{n-1} \cdot\left(-\frac{d y}{y^2}\right) \\
&=\int_0^1 y^{n-5}(1-y)^2 d y \\
&=B(n-4,3) \\
&=\frac{[(n-4) \cdot \Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(n-1)} \\
&=\frac{2 \Gamma(n-4)}{\Gamma(n-1)}
\end{aligned}
$$